# Set the values greater than x to x, and the values less than -x to -x

Tags: python, pandas, random

I've tried but am not able to figure this one out. I have to change all the data that is greater than 3 to 3, and less than -3 to -3 in the dataframe below.

```
np.random.seed(42)
randomdata = DataFrame(np.random.randn(400, 4))
```

I've tried for loops, .loc, .where and nothing seems to work.

Comment: I'm very new to this community and am hoping someone can help me understand why my question was downvoted so much? The site told me they're going to ban me from asking questions. I really value this community and want to make sure I'm participating properly!

Answer (score 1):

edit: for a panda, pandas has [DataFrame.clip](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html).

see [numpy.clip.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)

```
import numpy as np

thing = np.arange(-5, 6)  # [-5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

clipped_thing = np.clip(thing, -3, 3)

print(clipped_thing)
```

outputs

```
[-3 -3 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  3  3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Creating a data frame with 4 variables and 400 observations
np.random.seed(42)
randomdata = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(400, 4))
randomdata.head()

        0           1           2          3
0    0.496714   -0.138264    0.647689    1.523030
1   -0.234153   -0.234137    1.579213    0.767435
2   -0.469474    0.542560   -0.463418   -0.465730
3    0.241962   -1.913280   -1.724918   -0.562288
4   -1.012831    0.314247   -0.908024   -1.412304

# Cap and floor for one variable
randomdata[0].clip(lower=-0.5, upper=0.5)

# Cap and floor entire dataframe
clean_df = randomdata.clip(lower=-0.5, upper=0.5)
clean_df.head()

       0            1           2          3
0    0.496714   -0.138264    0.500000    0.50000
1   -0.234153   -0.234137    0.500000    0.50000
2   -0.469474    0.500000   -0.463418   -0.46573
3    0.241962   -0.500000   -0.500000   -0.50000
4   -0.500000    0.314247   -0.500000   -0.50000
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. I hadn't learned clip function yet so this is a real life and time saver!